# Spectral projection of a positive operator

Tags: operator-theory, positivity

Let $(X,K)$ be a partially ordered Banach space where the cone $K$ is generating and normal. Suppose $B$ is a bounded operator on $X$ such that $B(K)\subseteq K$,  the spectral radius $\rho(B)=1$ and every spectral value on the peripheral spectrum of $B$ is a pole of the resolvent of $B$. If 1 is a simple pole of the resolvent of $B$, then we have $X=R(I-B)\oplus N(I-B)$. Let $P$ be the projection on $N(I-B)$ and $Z:=B-P$. Then $P^2=P$, $PZ=ZP=0$ and $1\notin \sigma(Z)$. A result claims that $\rho(Z)<1$.

I have few observations: $Zx=\alpha x$ then $Bx=\alpha x$ since $0=PZx=\alpha Px$. So if $\alpha \in \sigma_e(Z)$, then $|\alpha|\leq1$ since $\rho(B)=1$.  Also if $\lambda\in\sigma(B)$ such that $|\lambda|=1$, then $\lambda$ is a pole of the resolvent of $B$ and hence an eigenvalue of $B$.

But I don't know how to use this to prove or disprove that $\rho(Z)<1$. Can anybody give some idea to check this?

Comment: Are you sure that the result is true? If I haven't made any mistake, $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $K$ the standard cone and $B$ given by $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ serves as a counterexample: $$P=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\quad Z=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix},$$ $\rho(Z)=1$.

Comment: The OP's claim is equivalent to the assertion that the peripheral spectrum of $B$ consists only of the number $1$. As @user539887's counterexample shows, this does not hold in the claimed generality. There are, however, various sufficient conditions for this assertion to be true. La Rias, could you specify what you mean by "A result claims that..."? Is this claimed somewhere in the literature?

Comment: Result from Lemma 4.9 (c) to (a) [link](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/01630569008816387?needAccess=true)

Comment: You gave a link to a 28-year-old paper behind a paywall:  I can purchase a 24-hour access for US$50 only!